# How to run function from web app locally and not on host

Tags: python-3.x

I'm want to create a web app so a user can run process locally on his computer (I know that currently it doesn't have a real usage).

So I use flask to create the web app and created a button that calls function that run the process.
Issue is the func runs on the server and not on the machine the user use.

For example to be clear: Server runs on machine 1.2.3.4, a user log the web app from a different machine 5.6.7.8 and press the button, the func will run on the host (1.2.3.4) causing the process to open on the host and not locally on user computer.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect
import subprocess


def runchrome():
    p = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        process = request.form["process"]
        if process == "Chrome":
            runchrome()

    return render_template("Home.html")
```

Comment: So, you basically want to perform arbitrary operations on a remote machine, if its user clicks a certain button in your web app?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run python code on the client's computer via a webapp in this way. Otherwise everybody could abuse this and run arbitrary code on computers that visit their websites. However, you can run javascript on the client's computer inside their browser.

For this to happen, you need to return a valid html document containing javascript. See this tutorial as a starting point: https://www.jitsejan.com/python-and-javascript-in-flask.html

Another way would be that the user installs your app on their machine.